# WSO2 APIM Analytics not populating Log Analyzer links in Admin Portal

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das, jaggery-js, apache-shindig

We have setup **WSO2 API-M** v2.1.0 with **API-M Analytics** v2.1.0 with Postgresql and HAProxy on CentOS. The API analytics reports are being shown as expected from the Publisher and the Store side and even the api availability from the Admin Portal.

This is a **distributed** set-up comprising separate publisher, store, key manager, traffic manager, gateway manager/worker and analytics. **Consul** service discovery is providing local **DNS** resolution.

On the gateway worker we have enabled **log analyzer**; also HAProxy is forwarding /portal and /shindig to the Admin Portal publisher node.

Also note the publisher was started on its **api-publisher** product **profile**, however this resulted in missing alert configurations, see
[*jira*](https://wso2.org/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/APIMANAGER-5614/APIMANAGER-5614.html) issue.

This is easily resolved by reverting to the **default** profile; still none of the log analyzer links are being populated when logged into the Admin Portal application.

When attempting any of the Log analyzer links from the Admin Portal the browsers javascript console is displaying the following errors :

```
"Failed to preload gadget https://<HOSTNAME>/portal/store/carbon.super/fs/gadget/LiveLogViewer/index.xml."
```

and

```
"Detailed error: 503 Unable to retrieve spec for https://<HOSTNAME>/portal/store/carbon.super/fs/gadget/LiveLogViewer/index.xml. HTTP error 503"
```

From the analytics carbon console I can validate my gateway log analzyer configuration from the data explorer seen here

[image]

The docs seem to suggest the need to edit js code for the log analyzer??

Comment: Reproduced the same issue with pattern 2 (standalone am, analytics and mysql) with docker compose and nginx. Followed the [reverse proxy](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Analyzing+Logs+with+the+Log+Analyzer) documentation for log analyzer but still facing

INFO - BasicHttpFetcher The following exception occurred when fetching https://am.dev.wso2.org/portal/store/carbon.super/fs/gadget/LiveLogViewer/index.xml: 4 ms elapsed.
[2018-03-22 16:22:28,562]  INFO - BasicHttpFetcher
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)